# Rolfsen exercise, chord theorem

Tags: general-topology, geometry, plane-curves, knot-theory

Here's a problem from Rolfsen's *Knots and Links* that has me scratching my head:

> Show that there is always a counterexample to the "chord theorem" if $n$ is not an integer. [Hint: In attempting to draw a counterexample, try holding two pencils at once.]"

Here's the "chord theorem": *If $C$ is a line segment of length $|C|$ with endpoints in a path-connected subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ there is a line segment parallel to $C$ of length $|C|/n$.*

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**My thoughts:** I can't figure out how to make the "pencil" hint work. I'm currently trying to prove that if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is not of the form $1/n$, then there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(x) \neq f(x-\alpha)$ for all $x \in [\alpha,1]$. Then the graph of this function will be a "counterexample".

**Update:** With the help of everybody's comments below, I've gotten most of the way to an answer, posted below.

Comment: Maybe you mean in "chord problem" that there is no line segment parallelto C, of length C/n and with end points in X? Otherwise, such segment of course exist. But if you add my requirement about the end points then the counter example is an obvious one, take X to be any compact continuum.

Comment: @studiosus: Perhaps my question is phrased poorly. I think Rolfsen is asking us to show that if $\alpha$ is not of the form $1/n$, then there exists a path-connected subset $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a line segment $C\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with endpoints in $X$ such that no line segment $C'$ with endpoints in $X$ is both parallel to $C$ and of length $\alpha \cdot \operatorname{length}(C)$.

Comment: Ok, them the solution is to take $\alpha=2$ and $C=X$, the unit interval.

Comment: @studiosus: I believe Rolfsen is saying that $\alpha$ is arbitrary, i.e. for **any** $\alpha \neq 1/n$, there is a corresponding subspace $X$ and chord $C$.

Comment: the hint means (I believe): try to draw a curve from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ with a red pen, while drawing with both the red and a blue pen, the blue pen shifted by $(1/n,0)$ wrt. the red one. You need to do it so that the red and the blue curves don't intersect.

Comment: @user8268: I appreciate the clarification. Now I have nothing to blame but my lack of inventiveness or hand-eye coordination. For $\alpha>1/2$, I can use a sinusoidal curve, but I'm still at a loss for smaller values.

Comment: I seem to recall thinking that the only values that actually produced a contradiction is $\alpha \in (0,1)$, which would make the new line larger than the one we start with.  It could "bump into the sides."  Also, does parallel imply empty intersection with the original?

Comment: @N.Owad: Thanks for the input, but I'm not sure that I understand. If it was $|C|/\alpha$ with $\alpha \in (0,1)$, then yes we'd have $|C|/\alpha > |C|$. Then letting $X=C$ would surely be a counterexample. But I think Rolfsen wants the reader to replace $|C|/n=\tfrac{1}{n} |C|$ with $\alpha |C|$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$, so $\alpha |C| < |C|$. We can certainly find counterexamples here too, as I've posted above a family of counterexamples for any $\alpha \in (0,1)$ that is not of the form $2/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments regarding Rolfsen's "pencil" hint, I've had some luck drawing a sort of "modified sine wave". For values of $\alpha$ that aren't of the form $2/n$, one can use $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x/\alpha)- x \sin(2\pi/\alpha)$, seen below for $\alpha\approx .37$. Now I just need to cover the case of $2/n$ with $n$ odd. Here's how we know it works for $\alpha \neq 2/n$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$:

Suppose $f(x)=f(x-\alpha)$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{\alpha}\right)-x \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\right) &= \sin\left(\frac{ 2\pi(x-\alpha)}{\alpha}\right)-(x-\alpha)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\right) \\
&= \sin\left(\frac{ 2\pi x}{\alpha}\right)-x\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\right)+\alpha\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\right). \\
\end{align}
It follows that $\alpha \sin(2\pi/\alpha)=0$, hence $2\pi/\alpha = n \pi$ and thus $\alpha=2/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

[image]

Comment: FYI for those who care, you can use $f(x) = sin^2(\pi x/\alpha) - x sin^2(\pi/\alpha)$, and that works for any $\alpha \neq 1/n$.